# Changing size of Dynamically allocating arrays

Tags: c

In C++, we can change size of dynamically allocating arrays easily with std::vector. So I wondered if there is any way to change size of dynamically allocating arrays in C without using any other arrays or dynamically allocating arrays and delete the first one?

I have tried in using with arrays to copy the first one then deleting data which I don't want to use. Now I am hoping to use in another brainly way.

Comment: Are you thinking of 'arrays' created dynamically with calls to `malloc` (in which case, your have `realloc`) or variable length arrays created automatically?

Comment: You can use `realloc`, but in a common case (when the allocation can't simply be resized in place), it's the same as dynamically allocating a new array, copying the elements, and then deleting the first one. Of course `std::vector` does exactly the same, since underneath everything memory allocation is the same in C and C++.

Comment: @PaulHankin _Of course std::vector does exactly the same_ - good to say that `std::vector` grow exponentially in order to preserve constant amortized complexity of insertions.

Comment: Does it need to be contiguous in memory?  Do you access the elements randomly or always sequentially?  If it is only sequentially, you could use a linked list.

Comment: You wrote _"I have tried in using with arrays to copy the first one then deleting data which I don't want to use"_. This sounds like a totally wrong (and even meaningless) approach. Show us that code, then we can tell more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  And read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  That will help us understand where you're having problems.

Answer (score 1):

Like some people have suggested in the comments, any memory block allocated with `malloc` can be resized with `realloc`. Its internal logic will do the copying for you, if necessary. Note that `realloc` returns a `NULL` pointer if the resizing fails, so code like this will risk you a memory leak:

```
int  data_length = 5;
int *data = malloc(data_length * sizeof(int));

...

data = realloc(data, data_length * 2 * sizeof(int));
```

You should instead do something like this:

```
int  data_length = 5;
int *data = malloc(data_length * sizeof(int));

...

int  new_data_length = data_length * 2;
int *new_data = realloc(data, new_data_length * sizeof(int));
if (new_data) {
    data_length = new_data_length;
    data        = new_data;
}
```

Do the same when decreasing the size.